# Outlook App Email (anchor, style, underline remove, costumize) > gmail

Tags: html, email, outlook, gmail, anchor

I have seen some questions about this topic but never found an answer to resolve it. So, I am reopening this topic because it may be frustrating for me and my clients. The goal is to style the **`<a>`** outlook, but for some reason we can't customize it. I am a macOS user, and recently, I delved deeper into this topic. I purchased an emulator to open Windows on my iOS and There I found.

**The original input:**

```
<a href="/" target="_blank" style="color: rgb(30, 30, 30); text-decoration: none;">
  Text
</a>
```

**Output, sending:**

```
<p class=MsoNormal>
  <a name="_MailAutoSig"></a>
  <a href="/" target="_blank">
    <span style='mso-bookmark:_MailAutoSig'>
      <span style='mso-ascii-font-family:Calibri; mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman";mso-hansi-font-family:Calibri; mso-bidi-font-family:Calibri;color:#1E1E1E;mso-font-kerning:0pt;mso-ligatures: none;mso-no-proof:yes;text-decoration:none;text-underline:none'>
        Text
      </span>
    </span>
    <span style='mso-bookmark:_MailAutoSig'></span>
  </a>
  <span style='mso-bookmark:_MailAutoSig'></span>
  <o:p></o:p>
</p>
```

Based on what I see, the **`<a>`** tag appears empty, and when I send it to Gmail, for example, it adopts the default CSS for **`<a>`** (underline).

This is where the problem arises, as there is a completely empty style.

```
<a href="/" target="_blank">
```

Is there any assistance available to customize this **`<a>`** element, specifically for setting **`text-decoration: none`**? Additionally, does it require modifications at the raw app level to send it with this styling?

Thank you

Comment: Could you explain how you're authoring your HTML email code and how you're sending it? The Outlooks on Windows do support `color: rgb(30, 30, 30); text-decoration: none;` so my guess is your problem comes from something else.

Comment: @HTeuMeuLeu, I have added the HTML to the signature. The color needs to be encoded in RGB to convert it to a HEX value afterwards. What you are seeing in the output is what the Outlook app sends. The question is about the <a> tag; it is completely empty.